# Calling Jar From Php (What if multiple requests made at the same time?)

Tags: php, jar

I am calling a Jar file on my php server via

```
exec('java -jar /pat/to/file.jar', $output);
```

But i am wondering, If two consequent requests made to the php function that runs the jar file, would the second request be able to reach the jar file? Or would it have to wait because the jar file is already in use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this in the past and it seems to work well: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/how_it_works.php